# I cannot figure out this sentence...need a little help

Tags: punctuation, ambiguity

I came across this complex sentence taken from an article. I guess I am having hard time understanding it due to its complicated punctuation marks. I'd appreciate it if I could receive some help with this.

"...where C1.5S1 – the product of synthesis after grinding and burning; Q – quartz; C1.5S(1+y)H  – the products of hydration; ΔH – heat; x – molar content of quartz in binding material; y – molar content of reacted quartz in hydrated cement stone."

Comment: You'll have to give us the link. Quartz is silicon oxide (SiO2), H seems to have two uses, and x is defined but not used. So something isn't quite right in the OP.

Comment: That's just a list of definitions of the terms in an equation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a table recast (somewhat awkwardly) into text form:

. . . where

```
     C1.5S1 – the product of synthesis after grinding and burning
          Q – quartz
C1.5S(1+y)H – the products of hydration
         ΔH – heat
          x – molar content of quartz in binding material
          y – molar content of reacted quartz in hydrated cement stone
```

It would be a little more intelligible if the dashes were replaced with *is* and an *and* were inserted before the free-standing *y*.